# Is this way for integrating has any fault?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have tried this $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2|x|/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2|x|/a})~~dx $
 integration in the method below- 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2|x|/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2|x|/a})~~dx\\=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-2(-x)/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2(-x)/a})~~dx +\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2x/a})~~dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{2x/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{2x/a})~~dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2x/a})~~dx\\
=4\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{4x/a}~~dx+4\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-4x/a}~~dx\\
=4\cdot \frac{a}{4}+4\cdot \frac a4=2a$$
I am not sure I am correct or not. Please help me with this integral and correct me if I am wrong at any step. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The derivatives bring down $4/a^{2}$, not just 4.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>0$. Function $f=e^{-2|x|/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2|x|/a})$ is even. Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f\,dx\\
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x/a}\cdot \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-2x/a})\,dx\\
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4 {e^{-\frac{4 x}{a}}}}{{{a}^{2}}}dx=\frac2a$$